# Bad Request in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I created a new form and when I try to submit it, I get the following error:

> There was an error processing this entry: Bad Request

And it shows reCAPTCHA box below the form!

I looked around but didn't find any similar case to this here. Can anyone please point out how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Developer on [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) here!  In general, this error can occur if there is a problem with the JavaScript on your page or cross-origin requests are being blocked by your browser.

I would be more than happy to take a look at your specific form.  If you could, please file a [bug report](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport/) and I will take a look to see if there might be something specific to your form that might be causing a problem.